# If I want to study protein translocation with RFP as a reporter should I fuse it to the C or N terminus?

Tags: cell-biology

I want to identify the whereabouts of the signal sequence (signal peptide) on a coding gene and I want to infer this by using RFP or GFP fusion and visualising the location of the fluorescence. Can somebody please explain how I might go about this (in layman terms) and how fusion to the C terminus vs the N terminus would alter the results.

Comment: What research have you done on your own to try and answer this?

Comment: I have been reading a textbook on protein localisation/translocation and looking through the literature but I think I have hit a mental block. I must be missing something.

Comment: Well, do you want to track the signal peptide or the main protein? Depending on your answer, that's where you put your [R|G]FP.

Comment: I want to track the normal localisation of a protein of interest. I just want to use the fluorescent tag (fused to the protein) so that it is expressed in the organelle its signal sequence specifies under normal conditions - i.e. I want to know its subcellular location.

Comment: In relation to above, is your signal peptide cleaved after the protein arrives at its destination or not? If it isn't, you'll have to think of another way to do your experiment.

Comment: It is more of a thought experiment than a real one. I am just simply trying to understand how fluorescent tags can be used to discover the localisation of a protein that is known to contain a signal sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer, we'll assume that we're working with Aquaporin's Localized Protein, or ALP for short. It has an internal cell membrane localization sequence at its N terminus which gets cleaved by a signal peptidase upon correct localization.

What will happen if we put GFP onto the N-terminal end of ALP, separated by 6 peptide flexible linker sequence? Assuming the signal sequence (SS) still works (and this is not always the case!), after translation the GFP-SS-ALP fusion protein will be shuttled to the interior of the cell membrane, where it is inserted into the membrane and the SS cleaved. This now leaves free GFP, which is soon degraded. Looking at fixed cells under a microscope, you'll see diffuse cytoplasmic staining, meaning you can't really localize it to a specific region. Fail. This process is called "*grad school*".

[image: green cytoplasmic staining]

<sup>Source: [biotium.com](https://biotium.com/technology/cellular-stains/)</sup>

However, you keep going. You express C-terminal GFP-tagged ALP, again with a short linker, and end up with SS-ALP-GFP. The same process occurs: translation, transport to the inner cell membrane, anchoring, and cleavage of the SS. So what's different? The GFP is still attached to ALP, and viewing under the microscope will show mainly membrane staining.

[image: green membrane staining]

<sup>Source: [biotium.com](https://biotium.com/product/membrite-fix-cell-surface-staining-kits/)</sup>

Comment: I got a good laugh at that grad school bit

Comment: Thank you for your response, this makes a lot more sense now. I appreciate it!